# PHP error_log and echo say different things

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a very simple loop over a mongo collection using the following code

```
function get_listing_by_name($name){
    $listings =  connect()->find(array("AgentDetails.Name"=> new MongoRegex("/$name/i")));
    $return = array();
    $i=0;
    while( $listings->hasNext() )
    {
    error_log('Looping');
    $return[$i] = $listings->getNext();
    $return[$i++]['_id'] = $listings->key();
    }
    error_log(json_encode($return));
    return json_encode($return);
}
```

I have tried multiple ways of looping through this data. It all gives the same result. The problem is that only the first item in the collection is ever returned. The loop runs 3 times, error_log at the end spits out all 3 items, but on the return call, only the first item is returned. The following does the same

```
function get_listing_by_name($name){
    $listings =  connect()->find(array("AgentDetails.Name"=> new MongoRegex("/$name/i")));
    $return = array();
    $i=0;
    while( $listings->hasNext() )
    {
    error_log('Looping');
    $return[$i] = $listings->getNext();
    $return[$i++]['_id'] = $listings->key();
    }
    error_log(json_encode($return));
    echo json_encode($return);
}
```

the echo only echo's the first item, whereas the loop runs 3 times, and error_log spits out all 3 items. This seems like a really odd problem and I have no idea why it is happening for something so simple

Comment: can you paste the array in the question please ? i mean output of `print_r($return)`;

Comment: Looks like the problem could be a # in part the output? [print_r result](http://pastebin.com/2TDNeEHB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The problem was that there were unescaped [ and ] in the result set from mongo and when they were JSON encoded it interpreted them as the end of an array. What I did was turn off the two columns that were causing problems because I did not need them.

Columns can be turned off in mongo using a projection as the optional second param to find()

```
$projection = array('AnalyticsClick'=>0,'AnalyticsView'=>0);
$listings =  connect()->find(array("AgentDetails.Name"=> new MongoRegex("/$name/i")),$projection);
```